# fatal error "Uncaught ReflectionException" after upgrade to 5.50

Tags: upgrade

WP 6.0  Civi 5.50
error is
Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class Civi\Api4\Service\Spec\Provider\SearchDisplayCreationSpecProvider does not exist in /home/lesley/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Api4/Services.php line 86

Answer (score 0):

Remove all file start with `CachedCiviContainer` in `files/civicrm/templates_c`

Example:
`files/civicrm/templates_c$ rm -rf Cached*`

There after civicrm will add `Civi_Api4_Service_Spec_Provider_SearchDisplayCreationSpecProvider` service to `CachedCiviContainer...` file.

Example:

> grep -inr 'SearchDisplayCreationSpecProvider' .
>
> ./CachedCiviContainer.4b01fcc15bfea5d03c88a31ab3b56016.php:1891:
> $instance->addSpecProvider(($this->services['Civi_Api4_Service_Spec_Provider_SearchDisplayCreationSpecProvider']
> ??
> ($this->services['Civi_Api4_Service_Spec_Provider_SearchDisplayCreationSpecProvider']
> = new \Civi\Api4\Service\Spec\Provider\SearchDisplayCreationSpecProvider())));